# Real world high insert (more importantly updates that resize the value) nosql

Tags: database-design, asynchronous, transactions, nosql, distributed-computing

I am working on a an IR problem that can be represented with two key-value tables.

Table Q : has a fixed size determined at time of insertion, updates to the table increment counters, the size can shift as the data is encoded in protocol buffers and as numerical go higher they may increase the byte size (variant int encoding).

Table P : contains references to table Q, it is a one to many relationship as one p can point to many q's. Updates increase counters and add references. Lots of fragmentation.

Table Q and P are exactly the same in data access characteristics to standard IR full text search structure of inverted indices. Q is documents and P is words - postings.

I tried the following embedded databases.

1. SQLite normalised form, too slow, not parallel, too much storage overhead. Performs the worst.
2. Kyotodb . Pseudo transactions (global locking) performance drops , increasing linearly past 500 k source lines. Tried a few different approaches.
3. Berkley db, page locked transactions, in memory. Performance becomes unacceptable past 6 million source lines. Cpu's are saturated but I expect deadlocks and spin locking are causing the usage.
4. Leveldb (I gave up quite quickly, it works under a globe lock IIRC). Perhaps it retains write performance. I didn't let it run that long.

This is the case I want optimised:

1. Storage / CPU time Predictability.
2. ultra high insertion rate.
3. Consistent but not durable (asychronous writes).
4. Designed for parallel inserts.
5. No Erlang, and no java.

And yes I Can fold the data model into a document oriented structure if needed. This will be a must for mongodb I expect since there are no transactions.

This guy seems to know what he is [talking about](http://perfectmarket.com/blog/not_only_nosql_review_solution_evaluation_guide_chart), and since he gives mongodb a 3 star in insert performance I am quite tempted. Even though Json seems wasteful to me. I can also switch to SQL server as it is amazing under insert load, but it doesn't scale beyond heavy iron. **So, is mongodb the bees knees for my scenario, anyone try hypertable vs mongodb ? Other recommendations ?**

**edit : self answer**

**premise :**

1. Large transaction scopes are the devil.
2. Fragmentation is the devil.

Therefore, before moving to a document oriented database or a distributed key-value database in general fix your application's data model to better map onto such data models. Distributed databases do not have transactions, and mongo goes as far as an atomic update for a single document -- So to use update in the scope of a transaction Q would have to be your document and P would be indexing variant elements within Q.

So, going to switch to a different representation for my data model. I am going to make sure both tables are statically sized for their lifetime (using protocol buffers fixed32 instead of int32), furthermore I am going to unpivot(un-invert) table P and to this end merge most of P into Q.

This will counter the fragmentation issue and also reduce transaction scope, inserts into P can be done outside of transactions. I am going to try out leveldb in anger as well. I have a feeling it will maintain it's level of performance throughout the processing, nevermind the fact that it won't parallelise.